# Error in Github while using ssh key in Ubuntu operating system

Tags: ubuntu, github, ssh, operating-system

while using ssh key of git in Ubuntu operating System I am facing the below error
Any help is greatly appreciated

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3PIr.png)

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure the repo exists.
2. make sure you entered your key correctly in github settings as described here https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: Yes the repository exist as well as key is correctly entered. I have checked it many times.